# AS statement ignoring cases in PSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

We are using the Node Postgres client to run some queries on our database, like:

```
await client.query('SELECT A.date_time AS dateTime FROM A')
```

the problem is that returned value for the row comes as:

```
Expected:{
  dateTime: '2009-06-16 11:00:00'
}

Received: {
  datetime: '2009-06-16 11:00:00'
}
```

is this a bug or are we missing a configuration somewhere?

Comment: Column names are case-insensitive unless you quote them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is case sensitive, but everything that is not a string literal or a quoted identifier is *case folded*. The SQL standard prescribes case folding to upper case, but PostgreSQL folds to lower case.

If you want case to be preserved in an identifier like `dateTime`, you have to surround it with double quotes: `"dateTime"`